# Removing item from generic list java?

Tags: java, iterator

I need to remove an item from a generic list in java, but I don't know how to do this. If it was a list of int, I would just set it to zero, if it was strings I would set it to null. How can I do this with a generic list, and I can't use an methods of Arraylist or anything like that, I have to write the method myself.

Comment: That doesn't remove the element. That sets it to the "default state". What are you intending?

Comment: Also, all references to objects can be set to null. Not just references to Strings.

Comment: To further what JB Nizet said, anything in a list is a reference to an Object, not a primitive. It's not a list of int, it's a list of Integer, assuming you really are using a list/generics

Comment: First, if a have a list of `int` and I add `0` what happens in your scenario? Second, what sort of list? Linked? Array backed? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: If you are implementing a list, you could remove the element by overwriting it with the elements after it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an individual object instance with [`List.remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) or you can remove a specific instance from a specific index with [`List.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29). You can also call [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) while you iterate the `List`. So, for example, to remove every item from a `List` you could do

```
Iterator<?> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  iter.remove();
}
```

Comment: *I can't use an methods of Arraylist or anything like that, I have to write the method myself*

Comment: @JBNizet Then it can't be done without *using* "an method of" an ArrayList (the only List/Iterable method used in the example above is `iterator`) as even `get` would be off-limits. That is, the example with the iterator seems sufficient / reasonable given the "requirements".

Comment: I have the feeling that the OP must implement a generic list, with a remove method. But the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if you are implementing a list yourself you should move all elements after the element you are deleting down one position, set the last one to null, and if you are keeping track of the size of your list, reduce this by one. Something like this

```
    public Object remove(int remove_index){
        Object temp = list[remove_index];
        for(int i=remove_index;i<size-1;i++){
            list[i] = list[i+1];
        }
        list[--size] = null;
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static <T> List<T> remove(List<? extends T> inputList, int removeIndex)
{
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>( inputList.size() - 1 );

    for (int i = 0 ; i < inputList.size() ; i++)
    {
        if ( i != removeIndex )
        {
            result.add( inputList.get(i) );
        }   
    }

    return result;
}
```