# How to remove element from List after getting it by random()?

Tags: java, list

I have a List with some elements. My method get random element from List like
`ListName.get(num)`
How can I remove element from List with that *num* I've got?

Comment: `ListName.remove(num)`.

Comment: Did you try `listname.remove(num)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing item from generic list java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567815/removing-item-from-generic-list-java)

Comment: Hello, and welcome! If you're wondering why this question has received downvotes, it may be because the answer can be found by reading the [documentation for the List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 2):

Call [`List::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) and pass the same number.

```
myList.remove( num ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listname.remove(elementnumber)
```